# Receive DTFM code in android phone?

Tags: android, dtmf

I want to receive **DTFM code** in **Android** which is sent by the **caller**. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* possible through the phone, as you have no access to the underlying telephony hardware.  The only way that telephony hardware is accessed in Android is through the [Radio Interface Layer (RIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Interface_Layer).  The frequent trick to play, is to force the user to play their call through the speaker, for which you see some [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wolphi.dtmf&hl=en) exist that will do this.